# Odd signature for a filter Func

Tags: c#

I was asked a question yesterday that is throwing me for a loop. I was asked to implement the interface `IPeopleFinder`:

```
public interface IPeopleFinder
{
    IEnumerable<Person> GetByAge(List<Person> people, int age);
    IEnumerable<Person> Find<TType>(Func<IEnumerable<TType>, bool> filter);
}
```

on this class:

```
public class People
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; }
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; }
}
```

The first function is simple, but the second function I do not understand what it is trying to do:

```
IEnumerable<Person> Find<TType>(Func<IEnumerable<TType>, bool> filter);
```

The `IEnumerable<TType>` in the `Func` is what I do not understand. If the signuture was:

```
IEnumerable<Person> Find<TType>(Func<TType, bool> filter);
```

it would be a simple matter of passing the `filter` to the `IEnumerable<T>.Where()` function.

Could someone please explain how filter function accepting an `IEnumerable<T>` and returning a `bool` would work? I'm starting to think it is a typo and should be `Func<TType, bool>`.

Clarification on restraints:

Classes are defined thus:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ushort Age { get; set; }
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public Major Major { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

`TType` is restricted to be of type `Person`.

The way the question is written, once the `Find` method is implemented, it is to be used to find all `Student`s majoring in a certain subject, and all `Teacher`s belonging to a certain department.

Comment: You mean a typo in terms of it should be`Func<TType,bool>`? , you might want to add this to your question. If yes, i agree with you.

Comment: Correct. Ill update to reflect

Comment: I think you'll have to ask for clarification on the relationship between `TType` and `Person`. I'd sort of expect to see a generic constraint that forces `TType` to be of type `Person` or a derived type. Also, just to be sure, `Student` and `Teacher` inherit from `Person`, right? `GetByAge` looks strange, too: why does it take a list of persons while the `Find` method does not? Should `GetByAge` search in the given list of persons and `Find` in the lists of students and teachers? Yeah, I'd ask for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously the method should work for enumerations of enumerations such as

```
var l = new List<List<Student>>();
```

Now you can call `myPeopleFinder.Find(x => x.Any())` which would return an enumeration of students.

A better example would be to filter those sub-lists from your enumeration that have a specific size:

```
myPeopleFinder.Find(x => x.Count() > 30)
```

EDIT: For a practical use-case imagine a school as a list of classes where every class itself has a list of `Student` and `Teacher`. Now you want to get all those classes that have more then a given amount (30 in my example) of `Person` (assuming that either `Student` and `Teacher` inherit from `Person`). Finally this method may flatten the resulting sub-lists into one single enumeration of type `Person` to get all the students and teachers within the overfull classes.

EDIT2: As you´re concerning to the properties of the persons instead of the list you should of course - as you´ve already assumed - use a `Func<TType>` with `TType : Person`. Seems like a type to me too.

Comment: I don't see why that should be "obvious".

Comment: Obvious from the signature. However the signature - as you´ve already mentioned - is a bit confusing.

Comment: This would work if you wanted to filter based upon the `List<Student>` properties and methods, but how would this be applied if you wanted to filter on a property of the student?

Comment: The signature clearly states you filter based on the list itself instead of the contained objects, doesn´t it?

Comment: The way the signature is written, that is what I would expect. I updated the question with additional constraints. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your analysis and I wonder what kind of specification you got and from where.

The person who defined the `IPeopleFinder` interface should not only write code but also document it, at least in source code, better yet: describe the reason for the interface in a requirements document, define the context in a software architecture document and describe the detailed use in a design document.

As long as you only have the interface and no further description, just throw a `NotImplementedException` since it has not been defined that you should do something else.